# Django - join two models

Tags: django, django-models

For the following models I want to retrieve all the devices that have an entry in the History table with transition_date between a specified interval:

```
class History(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(DeviceModel, to_field='id')
    transition_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'History'

class DeviceModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Devices'
```

I have this code that filters for the specified interval:

```
devices = DeviceModel.objects.filter(history__transition_date__range=(startDate, endDate))
```

That gives me as many rows as `History` table has with `transition_date` in the specified range.
The filter function performs an INNER JOIN between `DeviceModel` and `History` on `device id` retrieving only `DeviceModel` fields. My question is how do I retrieve data from both `History` and `DeviceModel` at the same time while joining them as with filter/select_related on device id.
I'd rather not write a custom SQL query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your models **Device** and **History** models are related with a foreign key from History to DeviceModel, this mean when you have a History object you can retrieve the Device model related to it, and viceversa (if you have a Device you can get its History).

Example:

```
first_history = History.objects.all()[0]
first_history.device  # This return the device object related with first_history
first_history.device.name # This return the name of the device related with first_history
```

But it works also in the other way, you could do:

```
first_device = Device.objects.all()[0]
first_device.history  # This return the history object related with device
first_device.history.transition_date  # Exactly as before, can access history fields
```

So in your query:

```
devices = DeviceModel.objects.filter(history__transition_date__range=(startDate, endDate))
```

This return a device list, but you can access to the history related with each device object

Isn't that enough for you ? You have a Device list, and each device can access to its related History object

**Info:** When you declare a ***ForeignKey*** field the models are related by id for default, I say this because you're doing:

```
device = models.ForeignKey(DeviceModel, to_field='id')
```

as you can see you're using `to_field='id'` but this relation is done by default, if you do:

```
device = models.ForeignKey(DeviceModel)
```

You'll get same results

---

***(EDIT)* Using .values() to obtain list [device.name, history.date]**

To get a list like you said `[device.name, history.date]` you can use `.values()` function of Django QuerySet, official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)

You can try something like:

```
devices = DeviceModel.objects.filter(history__transition_date__range=(startDate, endDate)).values('name','history__transition_date')  
# Notice that it is 'history _ _ transition_date with 2 underscores
```

Comment: I want to serialize those devices + history for each device and return them as HttpResponse, when I serialize them I only get the devices.

Comment: Add the history field you want to see into the quer y you're executing

Comment: You can serialize your query using django functions, what do you need as result of the _django_ query ? How do you want to serialize the data ?

Comment: I want to have a list of [device.name, history.transition date]

Comment: Try to use the query I added in my answer, it should return a list of dictionaries like: `[{'history__transition_date':whatever, 'name':whatever},{'history__transition_date':whatever, 'name':whatever}, ...]`