# Django cant figure out how to use foreign key

Tags: python, django, sqlite

```py
class Project_types(models.Model):
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_type

class Projects(models.Model):
    project_types = models.ForeignKey(Project_types, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project
```

When I try to run `Project_types(project_type='games').item_set.all()`
I get an error saying that there is no attribute item set.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890406/django-join-two-models`

Comment: all i want returned is a empty item set of the project type 'games'

Comment: Remember to mark the answer that solved your problem as answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Project_types(models.Model):
    project_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_type

class Projects(models.Model):
    project_types = models.ForeignKey(Project_types, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project
```

First there's a few problems with your model.

First model names shouldn't be pluralized

Here a Projects (should be Project) has one project_type, and a Project_types (should be ProjectType) has one project.

To run the query you want:

```
Project_types.filter(project_type='games').item_set.all()
```

the correct query would be:

```
Project_types.filter(project_type='games').projects_set.all()
```

use projects instead of items,

the related manager is based on the Model name (in this case Projects becomes projects_set)

see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

`Project_types(project_type='games')` doesn't actually return any object. That's why you got that attribute error. You need to add a filter or use get. Something like below:

```
Project_types.objects.get(project_type='games').item_set.all()
```

Or

```
Project_types.objects.filter(project_type='games').item_set.all()
```

Comment: ive tried using those commands and  im getting 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'item_set' error

Comment: If you are trying to get objects from this Model via filtering, remove item_set. So it will be: Project_types.objects.filter(project_type='games').all()

Answer (score 0):

The `.item_set` attribute does not exist on the instance you have created by running:

```py
Project_types(project_type='games')
```

---

It seems to me that you are trying to get all `Projects` of the type `'games'`.

To do that, you'll have to use the `QuerySet` of the `Projects` class like this:

```py
Projects.objects.filter(project_types__project_type='games').all()
```

---

Additionally, a suggestion: try to name all your model classes using *singular CamelCase*, so that they will be easier to understand. In your example, `Project_types` should be `ProjectType`, while `Projects` should be `Project`.